# Replace Span with a variable in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace the "showPw" span with the "userPw" value - I'm trying to do this using profilePassword, which is set when they choose to change the password.

If the page finds that one hasn't been set before, then it should bring the defaultPassword which is 0000

Currently, it only shows the 999 value, it doesn't update. Although I've tested the "userPw" value and it shows correctly in alerts, that and the defaultPassword, etc... any ideas?

Here is the Javascript:

```
changePassword: function(page){
        var profilePassword = window.localStorage.getItem("userPw");
        var defaultPassword = "0000";
        if(!profilePassword){
            window.localStorage.setItem("userPw", defaultPassword);
            $('.appProfile').find('span.showPw').text(defaultPassword);
            //document.getElementById('').value = defaultPassword ;
        }
       else{
           //alert(profilePassword +'--')
          //document.getElementById('showPw').value = profilePassword ;
           $('#showPw').val(profilePassword)
       };

    page.querySelector('[component="button/updatePassword"]').onclick = function () {
            var newPassword =  $('#setPw').val()//document.getElementById('setPw').value;
            window.localStorage.setItem("userPw", newPassword);
            //document.getElementById('showPw').value = newPassword ;
            $('.appProfile').find('span.showPw').text(profilePassword);

alert(newPassword)

$(profilePassword).val(newPassword)

             navigator.notification.alert(
                'PIN changed Successfully', // message
                null, // callback
                'Phindor', // title
                'Ok'                  // buttonName
            );
        //    window.localStorage.setItem("userPwOK", result.success);
        //    console.log(result.message);
        //    location.reload(true);
    };

    page.querySelector('[component="button/profilePage"]').onclick = function () {

        myApp.currentPage.myNavigator.popPage();
    };
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <ons-template id="changePassword.html">
            <ons-page id="changePassword">
                <div class="appProfile">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div style="text-align: center">
                        <b>Your current password: </b> 
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <span id="showPw">999</span>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br />
                        <b>Please select your new password:</b></span>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <ons-input type='text' id="setPw" name="setPw" placeholder="Type your new password here"></ons-input>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <ons-button component="button/updatePassword" ripple>Update Password</ons-button>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <ons-button component="button/profilePage" ripple>Back</ons-button>

                    </div>


                </div>
            </ons-page>
    </ons-template>
```

the whole www directory is here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/76bc6b9f75a44b7f7054036a7cf478ab20161226102828/3be6ca

I'm building an app with Cordova

Comment: Please show complete code that is necessary to reproduce this issue.

Comment: is change password part of an object?

Comment: I have added the www file to be downloaded, hopefully that'll help

Comment: changePassword is an ons-template being loaded as a page when the appropriate button is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after much trial and error, I got it to work using he below codes:

```
changePassword: function(page){
            var profilePassword = window.localStorage.getItem("userPw");
            var defaultPassword = "0000";
            if(!profilePassword){
                $('#showPw').text(defaultPassword);
                //document.getElementById('').value = defaultPassword ;
            }
           else{
               //alert(profilePassword +'--')
              //document.getElementById('showPw').value = profilePassword ;
               $('#showPw').text(profilePassword);
           };

        page.querySelector('[component="button/updatePassword"]').onclick = function () {
                var newPassword =  $('#setPw').val()//document.getElementById('setPw').value;
                window.localStorage.setItem("userPw", newPassword);
                document.getElementById('showPw').value = newPassword ;
                $('#showPw').text(newPassword);

    alert(newPassword)

    $(profilePassword).text(newPassword)

                 navigator.notification.alert(
                    'PIN changed Successfully', // message
                    null, // callback
                    'Phindor', // title
                    'Ok'                  // buttonName
                );
            //    window.localStorage.setItem("userPwOK", result.success);
            //    console.log(result.message);
            //    location.reload(true);
        };

        page.querySelector('[component="button/profilePage"]').onclick = function () {

            myApp.currentPage.myNavigator.popPage();
        };
    },
```

The main issue was the .val should have been .text in places like "$(profilePassword).text(newPassword)"

Thanks for anyone's time spent with this! I hope this is at least useful for people who have the same issue